# Name-ID-Subject Recorder with Alphabetical and Ascending ID Displayer and Subject Filter using Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, numbers, alphabetical

it has been 7 days since i have been started coding this.. i really can't understand what is my codes problem. . . why does my switch case never work?? the menu just returns without performing the specific function of the case..

i really need to know what the problem is.
.
.
.
.
.

```
package dakilangtaoako;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class DakilangTaoAko {
public static void main(String[] args){

    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( System.in) );
    String mydata[][] = new String[5][3] ;
    String inttoword [] = new String [5];
    int wordtoint[] = new int [5]; 
    int mychoice = 0, temp;
    String toreturn = "";

    for (int outside = 0; outside < 5; outside++){
        System.out.println("Entry no." + (outside + 1));
        for (int inside = 0; inside < 3; inside++){
        if(inside == 0){
            try {
                System.out.print("Name: ");
                mydata[outside][inside]= dataIn.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.parse("OK"),      null, ex);
            }
  }    else if(inside == 1){
            try {
                System.out.print("ID: ");
                mydata[outside][inside]= dataIn.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.parse("OK"),  null, ex);
            }
 }
        else if(inside ==2){
            try {
                System.out.print("Subject: ");
                mydata[outside][inside]= dataIn.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.parse("OK"), null, ex);
            }


 }
      }
    }

 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
 wordtoint[i]=Integer.parseInt(mydata[i][1]);
 }

       while(mychoice != 5){
       System.out.println("-------- DISPLAY OPTIONS --------");
       System.out.println("\t [1] Display Entries Alphabetically ");
       System.out.println("\t [2] Display Entries by Ascending ID number ");
       System.out.println("\t [3] Display Students Enrolled in Prog2 ");
       System.out.println("\t [4] Display Students Enrolled in CSO ");
       System.out.println("\t [5] Exit ");
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("\t Choice:");
            try {
                mychoice = dataIn.read();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            switch (mychoice){

                case 1:
                   System.out.println("----Entries In Alphabetical Order----");
                    for(int outside=0;outside<5;outside++){
                     inttoword[outside]=Integer.toString(wordtoint[outside]);
                    }

                        for(int outside = 0; outside < 5; outside++)
                        {
                            for(int inside = 1 ; inside < 5; inside++)
                            {  
                                     if(inttoword[outside].compareToIgnoreCase(inttoword[inside])>0)
                                   {                                         
                                    temp=wordtoint[outside];
                                    wordtoint[outside]=wordtoint[inside];  
                                    wordtoint[inside]=temp;                                    
                                    } 
                                    } 
                                    }
                        for(int outside = 0; outside < 5; outside++){
                        for(int inside = 0; inside < 5; inside++){

                            if(wordtoint[outside] ==  Integer.parseInt(mydata[inside][0])){
                                    System.out.println(mydata[outside][0] + ";" + mydata[inside][1]);
                            }
           }
                    }

                         System.out.print("Press [r] to Return to Main Menu...");
        try {
           toreturn = dataIn.readLine();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
                     if("r".equals(toreturn))
                         break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println(" ---- Entries by Ascending ID Number ----");
                    for (int outside = 0; outside < 5; outside++){
                            for(int inside = 1; inside < 5; inside++){
                                    if(wordtoint[outside]>wordtoint[inside]){
                                        temp = wordtoint[outside];
                                        wordtoint[outside]= wordtoint[inside];
                                        wordtoint[inside]= temp;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    for(int outside = 0; outside < 5; outside++){
                        for(int inside = 0; inside < 5; inside++){

                            if(wordtoint[outside] ==  Integer.parseInt(mydata[inside][1])){
                                    System.out.println(mydata[outside][0] + ";" + mydata[inside][1]);
                            }
                       }
                    }
                    System.out.print("Press [r] to return to main Menu...");
        try {
           toreturn = dataIn.readLine();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }            
                 if("r".equals(toreturn))
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println(" ---- Students Enrolled in Prog2 ----");
                    String mustfind1 = "PROG2";     
                    for(int outside = 0; outside < 5; outside++){
                    if(mydata[outside][2].equalsIgnoreCase(mustfind1)){
                    System.out.println(mydata[outside][0]+";"+mydata[outside][1]);
                                        }
                        System.out.print("Press [r] to Return to Main Menu...");}
        try {
           toreturn = dataIn.readLine();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
                  if("r".equals(toreturn))   
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println(" ---- Students Enrolled in CSO ---- ");
                    String mustfind2 = "CSO";
                    for(int outside = 0; outside < 5; outside++){
                        if(mydata[outside][2].equalsIgnoreCase(mustfind2))
                            System.out.println(mydata[outside][0]+";"+mydata[outside][1]);
                                        }
                        System.out.print("Press [r] to Return to Main Menu...");
       try {
           toreturn = dataIn.readLine();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
                  if("r".equals(toreturn))
                    break;

                case 5:
                    mychoice = 5;

                    break;  

                default:
                    System.out.println("Sorry the Number is Not in the Choices!!");
                    System.out.print("Press [r] to Return to Main Menu...");
        try {
           toreturn = dataIn.readLine();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(DakilangTaoAko.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
                 if("r".equals(toreturn))
                     break;
            }               }
  }      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
  mychoice = dataIn.read();
```

read would return single character and when it assign to int it would convert to corresponding ascii code

For example , if you enter 2 it would assign as 50 in mychocie 1 as 49 and so..

Change it to

```
mychoice = Integer.parseInt(dataIn.readLine());
```

Would read as string and convert into mychoice ( off course you need to press enter key after your choice )

or

change your switch conditions to 49,50,51,52,53

And you do have other issues such as

```
Integer.parseInt(mydata[inside][0])) which is name in your case 1
```

Update

I have modified your case 1

```
        Arrays.sort(mydata,new Comparator<String[]>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2){
                // Compare Name
                return entry1[0].compareToIgnoreCase(entry2[0]);
            }
        } );

        for (String[] entry : mydata) {
            System.out.println("Name :"+entry[0]+ ",ID :" +entry[1]+"Subject :"+entry[2]);
        }
```

Here mydata is your String two dimensional array, when the comparator calls compare method, it would pass String[] thats is actual entry. So inside the compare compare the `name (0)` position.

Incase if you want to sort by id , you can use `entry[1]` in compare method and `entry[2]` for Subject

You can follow the same pattern for remaining.

Comment: might i ask again... what is wrong with my logic in case 1 in arranging the names alphabetically.? please...

Comment: Let me check the case1

Comment: Just debug. inttoword is id holder i dont understand y u are converting back to string.. and so

Comment: thank u very much... i really really need to understand the error in my logic

Comment: in case two i found there was also a problem... any advise?

Comment: Hope you can understand and do yourself for other cases